# How to remove a row if sub query returns null value?

Tags: mysql

I have following query.

```
select
        Product.*, 
        (
        select
                group_concat(features.feature_image order by product_features.feature_order) 
            from product_features
            inner join features
                on features.id = product_features.feature_id 
            where
                product_features.product_id = Product.id
                and product_features.feature_id in(1)
        ) feature_image 
    from products as Product 
    where
        Product.main_product_id=1
        and Product.product_category_id='1'
```

I want to bypass the row if feature_image is empty.

Comment: Use Where Clause Where feature_image<>null

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks a bit strange because you are doing most of the work in a subquery:

```
select p.*, (select group_concat(f.feature_image order by pf.feature_order)
             from product_features pf inner join
                  features f
                  on f.id = pf.feature_id
                  where pf.product_id = p.id and pf.feature_id in (1)
            ) as feature_image
from products p
where p.main_product_id=1 and p.product_category_id='1';
```

A more common way to phrase the query is as an `inner join` in the outer query:

```
select p.*, group_concat(f.feature_image order by pf.feature_order) as feature_image
from products p join
     product_features pf
     on pf.product_id = p.id and pf.feature_id in (1) join
     features f
     on f.id = pf.feature_id
where p.main_product_id=1 and p.product_category_id='1'
group by p.id;
```

This will automatically include only products that have matching features.  You would use `left outer join` to get all products.